# What do we know about the relationship between IP, ZKP?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

The question is fairly simple and is actually stated in the title although I will elaborate a bit further on it. Also, I'm not really sure if this belongs here or it partly belongs to [cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Currently I'm trying to understand ZKP as a class of problems. I have read that IP=PSPACE and that ZKP exists under the assumption of OWF, and it basically is IP with the extra property of zero knowledge. I also have read that any NP problem has a ZKP, so NP $\subseteq$ ZKP. What do we know about IP and ZKP?

Edit : I haven't seen any classification diagrams with ZKP mentioned. Is there any resource available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that $\mathsf{IP} = \mathsf{PSPACE} = \mathsf{CZK}$ assuming the existence of one-way functions, see [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/88314.88333).

The existence of one-way functions is necessary, since it is already known that one-way functions are (essentially - there are minor caveats) necessary to prove that $\mathsf{CZK}$ contains $\mathsf{NP}$. See [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.8526&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [here](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Esalil/research/compzk-Apr06.pdf).

Of course, the first equality is for $\mathsf{CZK}$ with an *all powerful* prover. In cryptography, we are typically interested in zero-knowledge proofs where the prover is efficient given a witness. Having a witness for the language implies that the language is in $\mathsf{NP}$; it is known that, assuming one-way functions, all languages in $\mathsf{NP}$ have a zero-knowledge proofs with an *efficient* prover (see [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/silvio/Selected%20Scientific%20Papers/Zero%20Knowledge/Proofs_That_Yield_Nothing_But_Their_Validity_or_All_Languages_in_NP_Have_Zero-Knowledge_Proof_Systems.pdf)), and as I said above, one-way functions are necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think I found the answer, I would really like to hear if this is actually correct.

The site [complexityzoo.net](https://complexityzoo.net/) mentions the [following](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:C#czk) :

> Assuming the existence of one-way functions, CZK contains NP [GMW91], and actually equals IP=PSPACE [[BGG+90]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/88314.88333). However, none of these implications of one-way functions relativize (Impagliazzo, unpublished).

I'm not really sure I can understand the last sentence, IP=ZK under the assumption of OWF.

Answer (score 0):

unconditionally IP = PSPACE [Because of shamir]
Now NP contianed in ZK (if OWF exist). This is essential since to prove the zero knowledge aspect of the protocol you need commitment schemes that imply the existence of OWF.
You can essentially modify the PSPACE=IP protocol with commitments to get a ZK protocol for PSPACE, So PSPACE = ZK

(Here ZK is Computational Zero Knowledge [not statistical or perfect])